# rake aborted; SystemStackError, NoMethodError while running bundle exec rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am working on an existing project, which was made around 2014. While running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:82: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/bin/rake: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/bin/rake: undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        9: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
        8: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/bin/rake:23:in `load'
        7: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
        6: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
        5: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:185:in `standard_exception_handling'
        4: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:195:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
        3: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:208:in `display_error_message'
        2: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:218:in `display_exception_details'
        1: from D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:249:in `display_exception_backtrace'
D:/Ruby/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:21:in `collapse': undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

My Ruby version is 2.6.6p146, and Rails 4.0.0 (as required by the gemfile)

I've also read similar issues and tried `gem update --system`, but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really speak to that Rails 4 won't run on Ruby 2.6. But there's always a possibility that you hit subtle issues, depending on the features you use and the gems that you include. From Ruby 2.4, it has the Fixnum and Bignum unification, as well as unicode changes - which potentially could have an impact.

I suggest you to upgrade Rails version to 6 or downgrade Ruby version to 2.2.